# Laptop HDMI output fit to a 3.5" 320/240 px screen

Tags: graphics-card, hdmi, lcd, edid

So here is the scoop

1. I have a HDMI from a laptop outputting to a 
   (Adafruit TFP401 HDMI/DVI Decoder: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-tfp401-hdmi-slash-dvi-decoder-to-40-pin-ttl-display/overview)

2.The Adafruit Decoder is outputting to a 3.5" 320/240px screen (https://www.newhavendisplay.com/nhd35320240ftcsxnctp-p-9561.html)

Problem: The output to the 3.5" screen is not formatted correctly, part of the screen is cut off and the sizing is off to where only the top right corner of the output is shown on the 3.5" screen.

**Attempted Solution:** Attempted to change the EDID via Adafruit's suggestion
**Result:** I had no change in formatted picture for the 3.5" screen, 
**Possible problems with attempt:** The instructions on Adafruit's site are vague and I might have not done the flashing the EDID correctly

**Attempted Solution 2:** I tried to reprogram the output using the graphics card on the laptop
**Result:** could not detect the screen so I could not change it. 
**These are the graphics card on the laptop:**
 [Intel Graphics Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SJ1P.png) [NVIDA graphics card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2Ys1.png)

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved!

One of my soldered connections on the HDMI board was connected correctly so after fixing that and running adafruit configuration file it was successful in formatting the EDID.

I am curious though on how to create a custom 320/240 pixels EDID?
Any help would be appreciated.